# system sound services works on simulator but not on the iPad

Tags: ipad, audiotoolbox

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

SystemSoundID ReelStopSound;
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"spin" ofType:@"mp3" ];
CFURLRef soundURL = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &ReelStopSound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(ReelStopSound);    
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

when i run this app in simulator it plays the spin.mp3 but in the my iPad its not!!

Comment: i checked hardware switch and all other possibilities on iPad
every thing is working

Comment: Is the spin.mp3 file copied into the bundle resources of both targets?

Comment: @Luke yes, i can play same spin.mp3 using AVAudioPlayer

Comment: Hi can you please provide me with the steps to play audio in simulator in macbook?